# Twitter Bootstrap: console js error while rendering Modals with remote options

Tags: javascript, jquery, twitter-bootstrap

I have a problem with [Modals](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/javascript.html#modals) and remote option: if i provide a remote href for loading the content of modal popup from that url, when modal window appear I get this error in console:

```
"Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: /my/url" (jquery.min.js row2)
```

anybody with the same problem and/or solution?

Answer (score 0):

I have the same problem with bootstrap 3.
It works nice with an inline load (`href="#id"`) but same error when trying to load remote content, either via `href="remote/url"` or `data-target="remote/url"`

**Edit:**

I've found the correct way to do it.

Bootsrap allways need a modal container, to inject the ajax loaded content in it.
Thus, you need to give to your link both attribute: the remote target and the div to show.

Here is the simplest way:

```
<!-- The modal trigger link -->
<a data-toggle="modal" href="http://your/link" data-target="#my-modal" >modal link</a>

<!-- Invisible modal to render content -->
<div class="modal fade popin" id="my-modal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true"></div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem. The solution is to use **data-href** attribute instead of **href**:

```
<a data-toggle="modal" data-href="http://your/link" data-target="#my-modal" >modal link</a>
```

As **href** value, Bootstrap modal expects valid selector.